# How to use TryFindParent

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am writing an application using Mahapps metro. The custom popup dialog is derived from 'Window' and  the 'Owner' of their properties is set to the main window. In the dialog, the result of the TryFindParent is always null.

```
public class CustomDialog : Window {
  public async void doItButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var parent = await this.TryFindParent<MainWindow>();
    if (null != parent)  // parent is null. 
        await parent.ShowBusyIndicator();
  }
}
public class MainWindow : MetroWindow {
  public void showPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    CustomDialog dlg = new CustomDialog();
    dlg.Owner = this;
    var res = dlg.ShowDialog(); 
    if (null != res && !res.Value) return;
    MessageBox.Show(""); 
  }
  public async Task<ProgressDailogController> ShowBusyIndicator() {
    //TODO 
  }
}
```

And one more,What is the way how to diable the animation on the custom popup dialog showing up?

Comment: because window has no parent. You must search through the window's Owner property.

Comment: I would like to know how to use the 'TryFindParent'. I chcked the Owner property.

Answer (score 0):

A `Window` has no visual parent but since you set the `Owner` property of the `CustomDialog`, you could just cast it to get a reference to the "parent" window:

```
public async void doItButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var parent = this.Owner as MainWindow;
    if (null != parent)
        await parent.ShowBusyIndicator();
}
```

To disable the animation of a `MetroWindow`, you should be able to set the `WindowTransitionsEnabled` property to `false`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean TryFindParent is for the controls like Combobox?

Comment: It's a method for finding a parent element in the visual tree but as mentioned a window has no parent.